# Searching Techniques/Algorithms for Resources over a given area

Tags: algorithm, search, resources, area

I have a flat area with nodes randomly placed on this flat surface. I need techniques which are able to take a starting point, move in a certain way (the algorithm), find nodes and continue searching. I do not have an overall view of the surface (i.e. I cannot see everything), only a limited view (i.e. 4 cells in any direction). Ideally, these methods would be efficient in the way that they work.

Any points in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: With some small assumptions this problem reduces the problem of "painting" the surface. How are you allowed to move? Jumping nine cells in the X or Y direction would be ideal. If you can move only like a chess king, go diagonally (so as to paint 17 cells instead of 9). How's that?

Comment: I am allowed to move one cell at a time in 8 different directions. I would be able to move nine cells (taking nine steps), however is this the most efficient way to explore an area? I've heard about a method where you move in an increasing spiral, but i'm looking for more alternatives ;)

Comment: Raydon, do you understand what I meant about 17 instead of 9? Have you thought about the spiral? Have you thought about what "efficient" means? Have you tried to attack the problem yourself?

Comment: Do you have to find all points?
What is points density based on viewing distance?
Can you apply multiple searches/explorers on same area?

Answer (score 0):

Is the map size infinite, or do you know the dimensions, even if you ignore your starting position? Is it better to explore your starting position, or is the goal to explore greatest number of cells in minimal time?

If you want to explore your neighborhood with an infinite 8-connected map and 4-cell visibility in all directions, just do diagonal spirals. If the grid is finite, and you know the dimensions, it may be better to go in the same direction until you hit a wall (which will reveal your position), so you can plan your movements better from then on.

Answer (score 0):

Use a variant of [flood fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) - just add checking for a node after each pixel is filled.